# I am trying to add lines a textbox one after another in VS2019 - C#

Tags: c#, textbox, visual-studio-2019, multiline

I am trying to add 2 pieces of info to a textbox on consecutive lines based on whether files exist in a folder. After many attempts and not much success, I tried stepping through the program to find it does indeed print both lines to the textbox but the 2nd line seems to remove the first line for some reason. If I comment out the 2nd line then the first line is there but if I run with both lines enabled then only line 2 is visible on the top line of the textbox. The textbox has multiline and accepts return set in properties. I've tried using the Enviroment.NewLine and /r/n and combinations of both but it always does the same thing. Thanks for any help anyone can give with this.

```
if (File.Exists(SourcepathGLEXE))

            {
                LogBox.Text = "Game Loader EXE Found" + Environment.NewLine;
                FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(selectedPath + fileNameGLEXE);
                versionSourceBox.Text = (myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
                
            }
            else LogBox.Text = "Game Loader EXE not found" + Environment.NewLine;

            if (File.Exists(SourcepathCONEXE))
            { 
            LogBox.Text = "Game Loader Config Found" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else LogBox.Text = "Game Loader Config not found" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `RichTextbox`? If you want to append the value use `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: You probably wanted += (append) instead of = (assign): `LogBox.Text += "Game Loader Config Found" + Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: @KlausGütter this worked perfectly, thank you ever so much

Answer (score 2):

The `TextBox.Text` is a property. Therefore, the following lines will work:

```cs
string conf = File.Exists(SourcepathCONEXE) ?  "Game Loader Config Found" : "Game Loader Config not found";
LogBox.Text += conf + Environment.NewLine;
```